# What is the difference between "(type func())" and "type func()"

Tags: go

I'm trying to build a code example and I get the following error:

```
cannot use FuncName (type func()) as type func() error in field value
```

What does the wrapping parenthesis mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no difference but you're misinterpreting the error message. What it's saying is that type `FuncName` which is `func()` cannot be used as `func() error` because it doesn't return an error.